# Add folder name as attribute to all shapefiles in that folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have many folders with shapefiles in each of them. I want to use python to go through each folder, add a new field to all the  shapefiles containing the folder name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this challenge with [Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000).  Then loop through the feature classes and add the directory names using an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000).

```
import arcpy, os

# The input (base) directory
workspace = r"C:\tmp"

# Generate an empty list, which will be populated with walk below
fcs = []

# Walk through all directories and directories and list all feature classes
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        fcs.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# Loop through the fcs list, add field and add the directory name
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, field_name = "folder", field_type = "TEXT", field_length = 250)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(fc)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "folder") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = dirname
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Unsure if OP wants full directory path, or just the name of the folder.  If just the name is desired, replace `dirname = os.path.dirname(fc)` with `dirname = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(fc))`.

Comment: Nice addition @mr.adam.

Comment: That`s right @mr.adam ,well spotted and thank you to @aaron as well for the quick reply. You have both been much help. Any ideas how I can take this one step further and merge all the shaepfiles that have same filenames ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. What I would do is put `fc_dict = {}` right underneath `fcs = []`.  While "walking", `if filename in fc_dict.keys(): fc_dict[filename].append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) else fc_dict[filename] = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)]`. You'll create a dictionary where the key is the filename and the value is a list of all the corresponding files.  At the very end of the script, iterate the dictionary and merge each value.  dictionaries are one of the best things about python. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: like this: `for value in fc_dict.values(): arcpy....merge(value,output_fc,etc.)`  I assume the Merge tools accepts a list for input.

Comment: Thanks @mr.adam , i`ll give it a try but not sure where to eneter the second bit of code as i`m quite a newbie .

Comment: yes@mr.adam , the merge tools do accept a list .

Comment: @DhowalDalal I would recommend opening a follow-up question if you cannot find a solution in the GIS SE archives.

Comment: Okay will do @Aaron . New to this so still need to get the hang of things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, it would be misleading to give an answer to your second question here, and it's pretty messy to smash it all into the comments like this.

Answer (score 1):

as just an outline of ideas:
first you can get the folder name with something like:

os.path.relpath(".","..")

or also getting the path of directory  and parsing it using 'split'

or you could try using [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

then find shapefiles with a matching string (again parsing names as needed)
using [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001n000000)

you can iterate through

then pass that string to [AddField_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000):

arcpy.AddField_management (FC, fieldname, fieldtype)

then populate it with [CalculateField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/)

arcpy.CalculateField_management (fc, fieldname, data)